# Anyone know what controls/sdk mypad twitter use?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, twitter, sdk

It seems to me the UIs of twitter and mypad for iPad are very similar. I was wondering if anyone knew what sdk is being used as I'd like to use it in an app I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

http://cocoacontrols.com/posts/how-to-build-the-twitter-ipad-user-experience

Answer (score 0):

I doubt they're related although I grant you that they look very similar.

Comment: that's possible, they just look so similar, it's hard to believe they're not sharing an SDK